# assigned $output from search form not printing

Tags: php, forms, printing, assign

I trying to create a search form but there is something wrong with the `$output .=` , can't figure it out. I followed a tutorial and the function is working, but since `$output` isn't assigned correct, it prints nothing or only the . .

Here is the code:

```
<?php 
 $output= "";

 if(isset($_POST['fornamn'])) {
 $searchq = $_POST['fornamn'];

 $resultat = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM Garanti_tekniker91 WHERE fornamn      LIKE '%searchq%' OR efternamn LIKE '%$searchq%'") OR die(mysqli_error());
 $rader = mysqli_num_rows($resultat);

 if($rader == 0) {
 $output = 'Finns inga resultat för: "' . $searchq . '"';

 }
 else
 {
 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultat)) {
 $garantinummer = $row['garantinummer'];
 $fornamn = $row['fornamn'];
 $efternamn = $row['efternamn'];
 $telefon = $row['telefon'];

 $output .= '<p>'. $fornamn . '</p>';
 }
 }
 }
 else {
 header("location: ./");
}

print("$output");
mysqli_close($conn);

?>
```

Comment: are you sure result comes $resultat > 0 ? and where is $conn is declared.

Comment: Your query is probably missing a `$` in `LIKE '%searchq%'`

Comment: conn is decleared correct and im able to write to the database. Im not sure what the problem is. Now i've entered a new name to the database, but when i search for it i get the result that it cant find the name in the database.

Comment: as suggested by @kerbholz please do that Your query is probably missing a $ in LIKE '%searchq%'

Comment: @EliasA Try to print $row, check result comes or not ?

Comment: SELECT *
FROM Garanti_tekniker91
WHERE fornamn LIKE '%$searchq%'
  OR efternamn LIKE '%$searchq%'"

Comment: @SanjayKumar it prints "Array"

Comment: I've changed to $searchq

Comment: can you pls show me output result single array ?

Comment: <?php 

 $row = array('test', 'test2'); 
 
 foreach ($row as $value) {  
  $output .= '<p>'. $value . '</p>';
 }

 print("$output");
?>

Comment: where do i put this?

Comment: @SanjayKumar i put the code at the end of the search.php and it printed out test and test 1 below.

Comment: this is for testing, I think the problem with your queries. If you can share details, then I can help you.  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultat)) { print_r($row); } , check output

Comment: @SanjayKumar i got the output: 
Array ( [0] => 15 [Garantinummer] => 15 [1] => Elias [Fornamn] => Elias [2] => Aphram [Efternamn] => Aphram [3] => +46762409948 [Telefon] => +46762409948 [4] => 2018-06-26 08:20:16 [reg_date] => 2018-06-26 08:20:16 )

Comment: replace fornamn with Fornamn

Comment: @SanjayKumar now it works!! Was it as simple as a big letter?!

Comment: Great @@.......

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should prepare your variable:

```
$searchq = filter_var($_POST['fornamn'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
```

next, please use { ... } if you put variables in a quoted string:

```
$resultat = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM Garanti_tekniker91 WHERE fornamn LIKE '%{$searchq}%' OR efternamn LIKE '%{$searchq}%'") OR die(mysqli_error($conn));
```

and as told the commentator above - you skipped $ in your query.

Comment: I've done the changes, but lets say im searching for my name, which is already in the database, i get back a empty result. Nothing is printed out except for "Uppkopplad" which is that im connected to the database.

Comment: @EliasA That's most likely a different problem for a different question, since "Uppkopplad" doesn't appear anywhere in that code

Comment: I've created a table like yours, and I have a positive result, so I suppose your search word is wrong or does not equal with database word...

Comment: @kerbholz no thats not a problem, thats what its supposed to write aswell. If i change the to $output .= "Found it"; it prints found it. But it wont print the value from $fornamn. The issue seems to be here: while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultat)) {
 $garantinummer = $row['garantinummer'];
 $fornamn = $row['fornamn'];
 $efternamn = $row['efternamn'];
 $telefon = $row['telefon'];

 $output .= '<p>'. $fornamn . '</p>';

Comment: @Chudilka you can try it out, ive put a test page : http://support.mewebbdesign.se/

Comment: @EliasA please, provide the updated code of search.php . If there's no problem in a DB, it should be in code. :)

Comment: @Chudilka i've updated with the current code. And the site that the code is running on is support.mewebbdesign.se

Answer (score -1):

This code is up on support.mewebbdesign.se if you guys want to test it.

Updated code:

```
<?php $servername = "entered"; 
$username = "entered";
$password = "entered";
$dbname = "entered";
// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Kunde inte koppla upp.: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
else {
echo "Uppkopplad <br/><br/>";
}
?>
<?php 
$output= "";
if(isset($_POST['fornamn'])) {
$searchq = filter_var($_POST['fornamn'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);   
$resultat = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM Garanti_tekniker91 WHERE fornamn LIKE
'%{$searchq}%' OR efternamn LIKE '%{$searchq}%'") OR die(mysqli_error($conn));
$rader = mysqli_num_rows($resultat);
if($rader == 0) {
$output = 'Finns inga resultat för: "' . $searchq . '"';
}
else
{
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultat)) {
$garantinummer = $row['garantinummer'];
$fornamn = $row['fornamn'];
$efternamn = $row['efternamn'];
$telefon = $row['telefon'];
$output .= '<p>'. $fornamn . '</p>';
}
}
}
else {
header("location: ./");
}
print("$output");
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```